# How to read the value of a drop down list on a sheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As per the title, i have a drop down list which is already populated. On a button command i want to read the selected value from this drop down list which i will use to drive an ADO query.

I did VBA in Access years ago so have some idea of what i am doing but using it in Excel is new to me.

As a side question can anybody point me in the direction of reference material for the types available in VBA excel or any VBA Excel programming resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
    MsgBox "Index chosen = " & .Value
    MsgBox "Item chosen = " & .List(.Value)
End With
```